# Cannot get isValid in SimpleForm Toolbar, useFormState() crash because it requires control param

Tags: typescript, react-hook-form, react-admin

With react-admin 4, the Toolbar props like valid and invalid disappeared and where remplaced by react-hook-form hook. ["Toolbar Props Have Changed"](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Upgrade.html#toolbar-props-have-changed)

Using the documentation code crash at useFormState() `Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'control')`.

The following code is my toolbar:

```
import { Button } from '@mui/material'
import React, { memo } from 'react'
import { SaveButton, Toolbar, useTranslate } from 'react-admin'
import { useFormState } from 'react-hook-form'

/**
 * Save + cancel + delete buttons for a react-admin create/edit form
 */
const SaveCancelDeleteToolbar = (props: any) => {
  const { className, handleCancel } = props

  const translate = useTranslate()

  const { isValid } = useFormState()

  return (
    <Toolbar className={className}>
      <SaveButton disabled={!isValid} onClick={handleCancel} />
      <Button onClick={handleCancel}>{translate('ra.action.cancel')}</Button>
    </Toolbar>
  )
}

export default memo(SaveCancelDeleteToolbar)
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks to @MaxAlex answer, I now know that `const {control} = useForm()` creates a new form, and so even if it allows useFormState to not crash, it is normal that the results are empty.

useFormState control param is only optional if using FormContext. [useFormState API](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useformstate/).

For now, main lead could be related to why useFormContext() returns null.

**---**

My toolbar is called from any SimpleForm like:

```
const AnyForm = (props: CreateEditFormProps) => {
  const { label1, label2, label3, save, source1, source2, source3, toolbar } =
    props

  return (
    <SimpleForm mode="onBlur" toolbar={toolbar} onSubmit={save}>
      <TextInput
        label={label1}
        source={source1}
        validate={[required(), maxLength(50), noEmptySpace]}
      />
      <TextInput
        label={label2}
        source={source2}
        validate={[required(), maxLength(3), minLength(3), noEmptySpace]}
      />
      <TextInput
        label={label3}
        source={source3}
        validate={[required(), maxLength(50), noEmptySpace]}
      />
    </SimpleForm>
  )
}
```

This is how my `<SaveCancelDeleteToolbar />` is pass to my different forms.

```
const CreateButtonWithDrawer = (props:any) => {
    const {allMyProps} = props

    // Styles, Access, Title, handleCancel functions

    const memoizedToolbar = useMemo(
        () => <SaveCancelDeleteToolbar handleCancel={handleCancel} />,
        [handleCancel]
    )

    return (
      <Drawer
        anchor="right"
        aria-label={finalTitle}
        className={classes.drawer}
        open={isCreating}
        transitionDuration={drawerTransitionDuration}
        onClose={modalCancel}
      >
          <CreateDrawerContent
              basepath={basepath}
              classes={classes}
              closeDrawer={closeDrawer}
              pristinecallback={pristineCallback}
              resourceParam={resource}
              title={finalTitle}
              toolbar={memoizedToolbar}
              onSuccess={onSuccess}
          >
                {children}
          </CreateDrawerContent>
      </Drawer>
    )
}

const CreateDrawerContent = (props:any) => {
    const {allMyProps} = props

    const controllerProps = useCreateController({
        mutationOptions: { onSuccess },
        redirect: false,
        resource,
      })

    const { record, save, saving } = controllerProps
    
    return (
        <CreateContextProvider value={controllerProps}>
        <ResourceContextProvider value={resource}>
          {cloneElement(children, {
            closeDrawer,
            toolbar,
            // other props
            undoable: false,
          })}
        </ResourceContextProvider>
      </CreateContextProvider>
    )

}
```

And the component is called in each react-admin List actions, wrapping the current resource AnyForm

```
const AnyListActions = (props: ListActionProps) => {
  const { referenceRecord, target } = props

  const memoizedCustomActions = useMemo(
    () => [
      <CreateButtonWithDrawer key="createAction">
        <AnyForm
          referenceRecord={referenceRecord}
          target={target}
        />
      </CreateButtonWithDrawer>,
    ],
    [referenceRecord, target]
  )

  return (
    <ListFilterCustomExportActions
      customActions={memoizedCustomActions}
      exporter={false}
    />
  )
}

export default memo(AnyListActions)
```

I tried many things, but none worked.

1. Update packages version.
2. use FormDataConsumer to get form values (only them sadly), but I would have to revalidate them for each resource making the toolbar not universal.
3. call useCreateContext or useEditContext to get some infos, but isValid is not present.
4. Call useAugmentedForm hook.
5. Add validate or resolver props in SimpleForm.
6. Call toolbar with its TSX
7. Call toolbar in  children and with toolbar={false}

Please help, I would like to be able to disable my SimpleForm SaveButton when it is in an invalid state !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to do it as shown in the React-Admin documentation - ["Toolbar Props Have Changed"](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Upgrade.html#toolbar-props-have-changed)

```
const { isDirty, isValid } = useFormState();
```

Comment: Even if it is in the documentation, it does not work.
Without { control } param I have `Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'control')`.
And with the {control} param from useForm: isValid is always true after first render

Comment: So you have a problem with how you use your component, try this:
<SimpleForm mode="onBlur" toolbar={<SaveCancelDeleteToolbar />} onSubmit={save}>

Comment: When you call useForm() you are creating your own form unrelated to the React-Admin form.

Comment: `toolbar={<SaveCancelDeleteToolbar />}` does not change the outcome: `Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'control')`.

I understand now that I cannot use useForm because it "creates" a new form, how can I access current form `control` or bypass this typescript error ?

Comment: You don't need to use control anywhere, remove it.

Comment: I removed it but it is still required by useFormState() because it CRASH without it. In documentation it is said to be optionnal only if using FormContext, but useFormContext() returns null in my case.

Comment: You should in the question provide your full source texts,
what you have just attached is similar to the React-Admin documentation, and everything works there.

Comment: I Edited the question to remove my try with useForm and explained why. I also added full SimpleForm component. As I understand, it may be related to useFormContext being null.

Comment: The useFormContext / useFormState hooks must be called in the form context, otherwise they will return null. Obviously the way you make SaveCancelDeleteToolbar into a toolbar parameter, which you again didn't show, doesn't meet this requirement.

Comment: I do not know where my form context is supposed to be.

Isn't it the SimpleForm ? Anyway sorry I did not understand what you mean by show full source.

I added (with generality censorship) where is my Toolbar created and how my form access it.

Comment: SimpleForm, when creating a form, calls useForm() and passes the results of the call through the context to child components, in your case this transfer does not occur.

Comment: Try to work around the error with //@ts-ignore, maybe TypeScript just doesn't understand what's going on.

Comment: Sadly the //ts-ignore does nothing.

Comment: react-admin SimpleForm calls react-admin Form in its inside working, that use `useAugmentedForm` and `FormProvider`. As it is an inside working (node_modules ra-core) I cannot change anything.